# Adobe Flash videos stop playing after a few seconds

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, video, flash-player

From time to time, all Adobe Flash videos stop playing after a few seconds, on all websites and all browsers (at least Google Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and MSIE). Rebooting the computer solves the issue, but then the problem may arise again a few days after.

How to fix this issue, without having to reboot the computer?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Adobe Flash Player 20, on a decently fast laptop.

Demo on this [webpage](http://lci.tf1.fr/france/faits-divers/salle-de-priere-vandalisee-violences-xenophobes-manifestations-8699894.html):

[image]

RAM available:

[image]

I clearer all Firefox temp files:

[image]

Comment: must determine first if it is a network connection issue or ram and cache type of issue. When it occurs would a streaming video downloader grab it?  Would other massive sized downloads work fine over that network at that time when not streaming or playing ?  Run the program RamMap and check the usage, use the "empty" menu and start with standby pages (you can empty everything, it will just push out stuff that will probably have to load back again).  Clear all NetTemps your browser uses, make sure there is some available paging.  TaskMan kill the tree of any running instances of it before test

Comment: Thanks, Network connection is ok (100 Mbps symmetric) and a few GB of RAM is available. How to check cache type of issue? I don't use any streaming video downloader. I cleared all temp files in Firefox.  In the program RamMap I have emptied everything, it didn't help.

Comment: I just checked the Demo video in the link the server delivering that has no problem, and my older version of flash plays it just fine, there is also flash cookies occuring (normal).  Did you close everything before end process tree anything leftover?  The idea being to close the programs out then insure that there is nothing of them there, before clearing ram, the idea is to do what reboots do as much as possible without booting. your edit shows there isnt anything strange or clogged up.